# How to run a complex PL/SQL code in a Job created with DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, database

I'm trying to run a PL/SQL code inside a Job, but even though it runs (as shown on user_scheduler_jobs), it doesn't make the query. Please note that the query works if it's run on its own.

```
Begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'INSERT_LOG',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'Begin
        INSERT INTO PORT_ACCIONES (ACCI_USUARIO, ACCI_NOMBRE_APLICACION, ACCI_ID_PAGINA, ACCI_NOMBRE_PAGINA, ACCI_FECHA, ACCI_HORA)
        SELECT APEX_USER, APPLICATION_NAME, PAGE_ID, PAGE_NAME, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''DD-MM-YYYY''), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''HH24:MI:SS'')
        FROM apex_workspace_activity_log
        WHERE APEX_USER, APPLICATION_NAME, PAGE_ID, PAGE_NAME, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''DD-MM-YYYY''), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''HH24:MI:SS'')
            NOT IN (SELECT ACCI_USUARIO, ACCI_NOMBRE_APLICACION, ACCI_ID_PAGINA, ACCI_NOMBRE_PAGINA, ACCI_FECHA, ACCI_HORA FROM PORT_ACCIONES)
        End;',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    enabled => TRUE,
    comments => 'Llenado de la tabla de logs de manera automatizada');
End;
```

This is to fill

```
CREATE TABLE  "PORT_ACCIONES" (
    "ACCI_USUARIO" VARCHAR2(255),
    "ACCI_NOMBRE_APLICACION" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ACCI_ID_PAGINA" NUMBER,
    "ACCI_NOMBRE_PAGINA" VARCHAR2(255),
    "ACCI_FECHA" VARCHAR2(255),
    "ACCI_HORA" VARCHAR2(255)
    );
```

with the logs provided by ApEx, making sure it doesn't repeat entries and taking them from the application currently being used.

If not, I could also try as a solution a trigger that adds the registry to the PORT_ACCIONES table when a new insertion is made on APEX_WORKSPACE_ACTIVITY_LOG, but when I try to

```
Create or Replace TRIGGER "PORT_LOGS_BI"
    before insert on apex_workspace_activity_log
```

, it gives me the message

```
ORA-25001: cannot create this trigger type on this type of view. Any suggestions would be of great help.
```

Thank you all very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

How are you handling the `:APP_ALIAS` bind variable? May be its not initialized before the job is submitted.

Also, I can see a `single quote` mismatch on the first `TO_CHAR()` like

```
TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

this should rather be as below since the entire PLSQL block is a string text (`VARCHAR`)

```
TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''DD-MM-YYYY'')
```

Comment: I am giving it a value when the code is run, but that most certainly will change prior to development. Nevertheless, without that bit on the WHERE clause, the job still gets executed but not done.

Comment: Ok, so I updated my answer. Please try that and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

:APP_ALIAS is an oracle apex variable, which provides the specified alias for the application from which code is run **during an apex session**. However, a scheduled job will **not** be within a session, thus this variable will be empty at the time the query is runned.

Take note however that `:APP_ALIAS` **does not** equal application name! If you have not altered the alias in the application properties, they alias won't match the name.

The better approach to launch a job from an apex (page or application) process would be to use the `APP_ID`, and use `application_id` in your query. Can't go wrong that way.

If you want to launch the job manually, then you will need to provide the correct value yourself, since you do not have access to the apex substitution strings outside of an apex session.

You should alter the sql you provide to the job. Assuming you run the job creation within an apex session, concatenate the id in:

```
job_action => 'Begin
               INSERT INTO PORT_ACCIONES (ACCI_USUARIO, ACCI_NOMBRE_APLICACION, ACCI_ID_PAGINA, ACCI_NOMBRE_PAGINA, ACCI_FECHA, ACCI_HORA)
               SELECT APEX_USER, APPLICATION_NAME, PAGE_ID, PAGE_NAME, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''HH24:MI:SS'')
               FROM apex_workspace_activity_log
               WHERE application_id='||:APP_ID ||'
               AND (APEX_USER, APPLICATION_NAME, PAGE_ID, PAGE_NAME, TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''DD-MM-YYYY''), TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP - SECONDS_AGO / (60*60*24), ''HH24:MI:SS''))
               NOT IN (SELECT ACCI_USUARIO, ACCI_NOMBRE_APLICACION, ACCI_ID_PAGINA, ACCI_NOMBRE_PAGINA, ACCI_FECHA, ACCI_HORA FROM PORT_ACCIONES)
               End;'
```

Or, if you want to refer by name:

```
WHERE application_name='''|| variable_holding_application_name ||'''
```

Comment: Wait, that concatenates to what? Sorry, I got a little lost hahaha.

Comment: Btw, thanks for the answer! But even taking out the "WHERE application_name=''''||:APP_ALIAS||''''", the job gets executed but not done.

Comment: Where are you starting this job from? Do you run this within a page process in an apex application? Does your application HAVE an alias? Let's take a step back here: `:APP_ALIAS` is **not** the application name! There is no built-in substitution string for the application name.

Comment: Actually, I'm still trying to find a place to run this job for the first time - right now I'm just trying to solve as much snippets of code as I can, and then build the application as a whole. It only needs to be run once, right? 
I don't know if to place it into a page process; what would you recommend? 
I believe the application has an alias. So far, the query has worked with the aliases vs apex_workspace_activity_log.application_name.
Worst case scenario, I could replace :APP_ALIAS with the final application_name prior to deployment.

Comment: unless you mean to copy over the name of your application to the alias (which wont always work eg spaces), app_alias won't work at some point. You could use the APP_ID, or retrieve the name of the application through the ID, but you'll use the ID anyway. The issue remains the same: these substitution strings are only filled out in an apex session. You won't have an APP_ID or ALIAS out of this context. It depends then on how you want the job to be started. Do it yourself, in sql developer? Then don't use the bind var, but type it in yourself. If user-driven, use a page process to start it.

Answer (score 0):

:APP_ALIAS looks like a bind variable. Where does the substitution come from? Perhaps it gets defined in the environment where it works.

Also, is there anything in the job scheduler logs? Are you running as the same user in the scheduler that you are in the client?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say that I'm using that as "practice mode" thing, but even taking that out, of the WHERE clause, it still gets executed but not done.